# Constant number of Threads in a loop Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing an application using threads in Java and I have a problem with keeping the constant number of threads in a loop (new threads are incoming with new data).
I use ExecutorService to limit the number of threads, but I have a problem with starting new ones.

I have something like that:

```
ExecutorService execDownload = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
UniqList<String> documentList = new UniqList<String>("startfile.txt");
        Future<UniqList<String>> future;
        while( !execDownload.isShutdown()) {
            future = execDownload.submit(new Parser(documentList.get(i)));
            i++;
            try {
                documentList.addAll(future.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Parser is a Callable Object which returns UniqList. I add elements from this list to my global list which is collection of all documents names.
The problem is:
I want constant number of parsers running at the same time. If I would know all the names of documents before program start it would be simple, because I just should invoke ExecutorService submit() method i.e. 100 times if I had 100 filenames, but I don't know all the names of documents - the names are parsed by invoking this code:

```
new Parser(documentList.get(i))
```

and the names are inside the files.
So one more time the question - how to keep constant number of Threads, when new data is arriving? In code above I have only one Future Object and it it is my biggest problem I think - should I create array of Futures? But then how to detect when some thread from ExecutorService just returned some new data...

The algo should be (I think):

1. Start the program with initial parameter (first document name)
2. List item
3. Start Parser class by submitting it to ExecutorService and extract all documents names from start file
4. Add document names from #2 to global document names List
5. Create another Threads and parse documents with names from global document names List. Start the max number of threads (limited by ExecutorService). Parse every next file and extract new file names from them
6. Add names from #3 to global document names List
   back to #4

As you can see it is like recursion. I think it is the same problem as parsing the website, 1 start node, categories on first level, articles on second level, etc.

Links, or example code would be really usefull. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost sequential: future.get() blocks until the task completes so you won't be able to submit a new task as long as the previous one is running. You could either:

- submit N tasks in a loop and store the futures THEN try to call get on one if the future and submit a new task
- but that would be reinventing the wheel: a [CompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) seems to do exactly what you need.

Comment: I know, it's just a sample - that's why I asked about array of Futures. I will try try CompletionService, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest ditching the future, and constructing the Parser to know about the executor:

```
execDownload.submit(new Parser(execDownload, documentList.get(i)));
```

Have Parser store this "execDownload" ExecutorService as a member variable.

At the end of Parser.run(), when you have your newly parsed list of document names, you create new Parsers for them, and schedule them, too:

```
foreach (String newDoc: UniqList)
{
     execDownload.submit(new Parser(execDownload, newDoc));
}
```